# Need advice optimizing SQL query (update on MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I did a performance profiling on my database with the slow query log. It turned out this is the number one annoyance:

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET
  v1t1 =
  (
    SELECT
        t2.v3t2
    FROM
        t2
    WHERE
        t2.v2t2 = t1.v2t1
    AND t2.v1t2 <= '2012-04-24'
    ORDER BY
        t2.v1t2 DESC,
        t2.v3t2 DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

The subquery itself is already slow. I tried variations with DISTINCT, GROUP BY and more subqueries but nothing performed below 4 seconds. For example the following query

```
SELECT v2t2, v3t2
FROM t2
WHERE t2.v1t2 <= '2012-04-24'
GROUP BY v2t2
ORDER BY v1t2 DESC
```

takes:

```
mysql> SELECT ...
...    
69054 rows in set (5.61 sec)    

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT ...
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2          | ALL  | v1t2          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 5203965 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE t2;
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`v3t2`),
  KEY `v1t2_v3t2` (`v1t2`,`v3t2`),
  KEY `v1t2` (`v1t2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    77070 |
+----------+

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  5203965 |
+----------+
```

I am trying to fetch the newest entry (v3t2) and its parent (v2t2). Should not be that big of a deal, should it? Does anyone have any advice which knobs I should turn? Any help or hint is greatly appreciated!

This should be a more appropriate SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
    t1.v2t1,
  (
    SELECT
        t2.v3t2
    FROM
        t2
    WHERE
        t2.v2t2 = t1.v2t1
    AND t2.v1t2 <= '2012-04-24'
    ORDER BY
        t2.v1t2 DESC,
        t2.v3t2 DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS latest   
FROM
    t1
```

Comment: Your subquery filters on a `PRIMARY KEY` (`v2t2`). Why `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` within it? Are you sure you posted the query and the table definition right?

Comment: Your second SELECT is wildly different than your problem SELECT (no LIMIT, no JOIN, etc.) The optimizer has no choice but to do a table scan, since you effectively asked for all rows. Try doing an EXPLAIN on the actual problem query.

Comment: These names `v1t1, v2t1, v1t3, ..., v7t3` are hurting my eyes.

Comment: @MarkBrackett In my version of MySQL I cannot do an EXPLAIN on an UPDATE statement. That´s why I tried to construct a query whose result is similar to the one in my subquery.

Comment: @openHaus - EXPLAIN the SELECT subquery in your UPDATE statement. Your "similar" query is missing many of the operators of your subquery, which is where any optimization will have to occur.

Comment: @MarkBrackett See my latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` is forcing database to perform a full scan of the table to return only 1 row. It looks like very much as a candidate for indexing.

Before you build the index, check the fileds selectivity by running:

```sql
SELECT count(*), count(v1t2), count(DISTINCT v1t2) FROM t2;
```

If you're having high number of non-`NULL` values in your column and number of distinct values is more then 40% of the non-`NULL`s, then building index is a good thing to go.

If index provides no help, you should analyze the data in your columns. You're using `t2.v1t2 <= '2012-04-24'` condition, which, in the case you have a historical set of records in your table, will give nothing to the planner, as all rows are expected to be in the past, thus full scan is the best choice anyway. Thus, indexe is useless.

What you should do instead, is think how to rewrite your query in a way, that only a limited  subset of records is checked. Your construct `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1` shows that you probably want the most recent entry up to `'2012-04-24'` (including). Why don't you try to rewrite your query to a something like:

```sql
SELECT v2t2, v3t2
FROM t2
WHERE t2.v1t2 => date_add('2012-04-24' interval '-10' DAY)
GROUP BY v2t2
ORDER BY v1t2 DESC;
```

This is just an example, knowing the design of your database and nature of your data more precise query can be built.

Comment: Why grouping on a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @Quassnoi My fault. The primary key is _v3t2_.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at indexes that are built for the sub-select t2.  You should have a index for v2t2 and possibly one for v1t2, and v3t2 because of the ordering.  The index should reduce the time the sub select has to go looking for the results before using them in your update query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work any better? Gets rid of one of the sorts and groups by the key being used.

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET
  v1t1 =
  (
    SELECT
        MAX(t2.v3t2)
    FROM
        t2
    WHERE
        t2.v2t2 = t1.v2t1
    AND t2.v1t2 <= '2012-04-24'
    GROUP BY t2.v1t2
    ORDER BY t2.v1t2 DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

### Alternate Version

```
UPDATE `t1`
SET `v1t1` = (
  SELECT MAX(`t2`.`v3t2`)
  FROM `t2`
  WHERE `t2`.`v2t2` = `t1`.`v2t1`
  AND `t2`.`v1t2` = (
    SELECT MAX(`t2`.`v1t2`)
    FROM `t2`
    WHERE `t2`.`v2t2` = `t1`.`v2t1
    AND `t2`.`v1t2` <= '2012-04-24'
    LIMIT 1
  )
  LIMIT 1
);
```

**And add this index to `t2`:**

```
KEY `v2t2_v1t2` (`v2t2`, `v1t2`)
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in the GROUP BY? Shouldn´t it be _t2.v2t2_?

Comment: @OpenHaus, nope, I typed it correctly (although, it may not work). The idea behind it is you were previously ordering by `v1t2` and then by `v3t2`. So, you *do* need `v1t2` ordered, even though you're grouping by it. The `GROUP BY` is to narrow the results before the sort occurs (*should* be faster). Then, `MAX()` is used to grab the greatest `v3t2` value in the group with the max `v1t2` value.

Comment: @OpenHaus, I've also added an alternate version of the query that uses a second `SELECT` statement. I'd suggest trying each of them and using the faster :)

Comment: Query OK, 1594 rows affected (8 min 1.46 sec)
Rows matched: 77076  Changed: 1594  Warnings: 0

Comment: @OpenHaus, was that the first or alternate query? Also, please add the index listed in the answer.

Comment: It was the alternate version but I had to modify it a little. With the GROUP BY `t2`.`v1t2` in the subquery it fetches the oldest (minimum) date.

Comment: @OpenHaus, oops, *that* was a typo. How did the query do with the index added for `v2t21`,`v1t2`?

Comment: The time shown is with the index already added. The first version takes 44 seconds for my super small test set with only 1000 entries. I had to abort the query on the real data.

Comment: @OpenHaus, you're using `v2t2_v1t2` and **not** `v1t2_v3t2`, correct? (There's a big difference.) Could you post an explain? And how about the alternate version?